# how can i delete/update author name if book name is updated or deleted using RESTapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, react-fullstack

CREATE A REST API
a. Create a database using NODE.JS AND MONGODB containing two tables Books and Authors. Add appropriate columns to the tables. Every book has a single author and referential integrity should be maintained

b. Create a Rest API which supports the following operations:
i. Insert, update and select on Books
i. Handle exception for adding Authors who are not present in the table.

cannot understand  how can i delete author name if book name is updated or deleted

Answer (score 0):

I do not think I understand you question well, maybe you can give more information or add the code but if you are asking about how you can delete changed or updated book you simply can't if you don't know the correct name of the author just in real life if you are searching for a book you need the real name

Comment: Hey @obeda   can you guide me how to do this.       ->>CREATE A REST API                                    
 a. Create a database using NODE.JS AND MONGODB containing two tables Books and Authors. Add appropriate columns to the tables. Every book has a single author and referential integrity should be maintained

b. Create a Rest API which supports the following operations: i. Insert, update and select on Books i. Handle exception for adding Authors who are not present in the table.

Comment: I can't go with you step by step but I can recommend good tutorial for you https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/index.htm